# Data stored in SwiftData is not updating when trying to update using firebase data

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have 2 SwiftData models in my SwiftUI app, `GroceryList` and `GroceryItem`. `GroceryList` has a one-to-many relationship with `GroceryItem`:

GroceryList Model:

```
@Model
class GroceryList: Codable, Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id    = UUID().uuidString
    var title : String
    var color : Int
    var icon  : String
    var users = [User]()
    var items = [GroceryItem]()
    // Rest of the code
}
```

GroceryItem Model:

```
@Model
class GroceryItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var id              : String?
    var store           : String?
    var category        : String?
    var subCategory     : String?
    var name            : String
    var itemDescription : [DescriptionItem]?
    var price           : String?
    var pricePerType    : String?
    var image           : String?
    var url             : String?
    
    var groceryList     : GroceryList?
    var quantity        = 1
    // Rest of the code
}
```

Users can create lists (`GroceryList`) and these lists will be stored locally using SwiftData and in Firestore. When the app launches, the locally stored data is fetched like so  `@Query(sort: \GroceryList.title) var allLists: [GroceryList]` and displayed in a List view.

The lists can also be shared with other users, once shared, any changes made to the list by any of the users is updated locally and in Firestore.

So let's say, userA creates a lists and shares it with userB. Now they both have the same lists. userA now changes the title of the list (`GroceryList`) and adds an item to the items array (this is the array of type `GroceryItem` inside the `GroceryList` model). These changes are being successfully updated in Firestore. So, these changes have to be shown to the userB, right? I have created a listener for these documents in Firestore so when ever any changes are made in Firestore, the swiftui app retrieves the new changes. Alright, now the changes are retrieved successfully. We now have to update the userB's data and show them the updated list. Here's the code where the updating takes places:

```
func saveDBListLocally(context: ModelContext) {
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<GroceryList>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\GroceryList.title)])
    
    do {
        var fetchedLists = try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor)

        for list in allDBLists { // allDBLists is the data from Firestore, it's an array of type GroceryList
            if let index = fetchedLists.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == list.id }) {
                fetchedLists[index] = list
                // context.insert(list) -> Tried this but no luck
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Successfully updated local data with DB data")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    } catch {
        print("Error when trying to fetch the saved grocery items in SwiftData")
    }
}
```

What's happening right now is that, the `title` is being updated but items array (of type `GroceryItem`) in the `GroceryList` are not being updated properly. Not all the `items` are shown all the time. Sometimes, all the `items` are displayed, other times, some of the `items` are missing. There are no issues with the data being retrieved from Firestore. Please do let me know if I need to add more info.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The for loop iterates through the Firestore data and checks if the id of each item is equal to the items in the local data. If it's equal, then Iit updates the data (which doesn't work properly). GroceryList has a one-to-many relationship with GroceryItem. GroceryList contains an array of type GroceryItem. When I update a local GroceryList with one from Firesotre, the groceryItems are not updated properly. I don't understand your last question, please elaborate.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am updating the fetch list because that stores the local data. Some of the local data have the same ids as the ones in Firestore, which is why I am doing a check here: `if let index = fetchedLists.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == list.id })` If the ids are same, then we go ahead and update the local data. So this means that the code will get executed, and it does, I checked using print statements.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "why doesn’t the insert work?" That's the problem, like I mentioned, sometimes it shows all the correct data, other times, it's missing some data. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have edited the question with a better explanation. If you want, we can move this discussion to chat.

Comment: After the latest update I understand better what you want to do, I think you need to loop through the items list in the same way to check what has been added, changed or removed and take the corresponding action for each.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson tried that just now, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic tries to directly replace the `GroceryList` object in the fetched array. That approach might not trigger the necessary property observers or the internal mechanisms of [SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/) to correctly update the relationship data, especially for complex objects like arrays or nested objects.

Simply replacing a `GroceryList` in the fetched array does not update the nested `GroceryItem` relationships as expected: the update mechanism might not fully account for nested structures or relational data.
Hence, the suggestion to individually loop through the items and check for additions, changes, or removals because updating complex nested structures often requires more granular control than what high-level replacements offer.

While the original question about transaction support remains relevant, the immediate problem seems more related to how data relationships are managed during updates. So try and make sure that each `GroceryItem` within a `GroceryList` is individually checked and updated.
See "[Map Cloud Firestore data with Swift Codable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping)"

- When updating a `GroceryList`, do not rely on replacing the object. Instead, explicitly update each property of the `GroceryList`, including iterating through the `GroceryItem` array to manage each item individually.
- compare the current `GroceryItem`s in the local storage with the updated list from Firestore.
  That means, for each item, determine if it needs to be added, updated, or removed:

  - Check if an item exists locally by ID.
  - If it exists, update its properties.
  - If it does not exist, add the new item.
  - If an item exists locally but not in the updated Firestore list, consider removing it.

```swift
func updateGroceryList(from list: GroceryList, in context: ModelContext) {
    do {
        if let existingList = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<GroceryList>().filter(\.id == list.id)).first {
            // Update simple properties
            existingList.title = list.title
            existingList.color = list.color
            // Explicitly manage `items` updates
            updateItems(for: existingList, with: list.items, in: context)
            try context.save()
        } else {
            // If the list does not exist, insert it as new
            try context.insert(list)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error updating list: \(error)")
    }
}

func updateItems(for existingList: GroceryList, with newItems: [GroceryItem], in context: ModelContext) {
    // Detailed logic for comparing and updating items
}
```

---

But if, as commented, this is not enough, then you would need to add detailed logging around the code that handles the updating of `GroceryItems`. Log not only the operations (add, update, remove) but also the state of the items before and after the attempted update.

As a troubleshooting step or potential workaround, consider re-fetching the entire `GroceryList` from Firestore upon notification of a change, instead of trying to update the local copy incrementally. That can help determine if the issue lies in the update logic versus fetching or model instantiation.

If not already attempted, use [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for the update logic. Transactions can help make sure your updates are consistent and atomic. That is particularly useful when dealing with nested objects and relationships, where partial updates could lead to inconsistent states.

Make sure your `GroceryItem` and `GroceryList` models are correctly annotated and that their Codable implementation aligns with the Firestore document structure.

You can also temporarily *simplify* your data model to troubleshoot. For instance, try updating a single `GroceryItem` or a simplified version of `GroceryList` without nested items.
That can help isolate the issue to either the data model complexity or the update logic itself.